# Why is there an extra line after my output?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
int main()
{
    char str[100];
    char splitStrings[10][10];
    int i, j, cnt;

    printf("Enter a sentence, up to 255 charcters: \n");
    fgets(str, sizeof str, stdin);

    j = 0; cnt = 0;
    for (i = 0; i <= (strlen(str)); i++)
    {
        if (!ispunct(str[i]) == ' ' || isalpha(str[i]) == '\0')
        {
            splitStrings[cnt][j] = '\0';
            cnt++;  //for next word
            j = 0;    //for next word, init index to 0
        }
        else
        {
            splitStrings[cnt][j] = str[i];
            j++;
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < cnt; i++)
        printf("\n%s %d \n",  splitStrings[i], strlen(splitStrings[i]));
    return 0;
}
```

Here is my code, I am trying to input a sentence and it will spilt up the string by words and count the number of letter. But it appear there an additional 0 in my output? And how do I get rid of it
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VkiS9.jpg)

Comment: `!ispunct(str[i])` will be 0 or 1, so `!ispunct(str[i]) == ' '` will never true in typical environment.

Comment: Please don't post images of text — include the text in the question (formatted as if it were  code).

Comment: "Why is there an extra line after my output?" Because you are printing an empty string.

Comment: `if (!ispunct(str[i]) == ' ' || isalpha(str[i]) == '\0')` -> `if (!ispunct(str[i]) || !isalpha(str[i]))`. Read the documentation of these functions and specially the part that deals with the value they return.

Comment: Note the inconsistency in: `char str[100];` — `printf("Enter a sentence, up to 255 charcters: \n");` — `fgets(str, sizeof str, stdin);` — A user won't be able to enter more than 99 characters (or 98 characters plus newline and null) given that the array is of size 100.  It might be best to print the array size in the message — using `%zu` to format `sizeof(str)`.

Answer (score 2):

`fgets()` will put a newline character it read into the buffer when the input is short enough to fit (as in the example data).

The newline character is not an alphabet, so `isalpha(str[i]) == '\0'` will become true and it moves on next word.

Then, the next charcter is terminating null-character. (it is processed because the loop condition is `i <= (strlen(str))`)
It is also not an alphabet, so it also moves on next word.

There are no characters between the newline character and the terminating null-character, so it is printed as zero-character word.

Comment: Do you mean a string of length zero (or empty string), when you wrote "zero-character"?

Comment: @JeffHolt — yes.

Comment: Hi, there how i changed the if statement to (!isalpha(str[i])) however it's still looping for non alphabet. Sorry I am new to C